# Is there any filter option for X-MessageID from SendGrid response?

Tags: twilio, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-api-v2

I have SendGrid response and here I get individual `X-MessageID` which is unique for all sent email, this `X-MessageID` is actually a starting position of Sendgrid MessageID. So here I was doing something like this "Sendgrid_MessageID Start with X-MessageID",
*For.Ex* 'KdLh1ZETSQCWx0iqU44BTg.filterdrecv-75d94df84d-4c444-1-627963D1-45.3' start with 'KdLh1ZETSQCWx0iqU44BTg'.  I have done this using SendGrid "like" operator like this =>

`msg_id like 'KdLh1ZETSQCWx0iqU44BTg%'`

and also try another option like

`query=msg_id like 'KdLh1ZETSQCWx0iqU44BTg%'`

But I get error 'invalid value' for both option, I don't undertstand how to use it. Anyone knows about how to use this "like" operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the like operator correctly.
When I make the following HTTP GET request using cURL, I get the message back that start with the given ID:

```bash
curl -X GET https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/messages \
--header "Authorization: Bearer [SENDGRID_API_KEY]" \
--data-urlencode "query=msg_id LIKE 'W86EgYT6SQKk0lRflfLRsA%'" \
--data-urlencode "limit=10" --GET
```

How are you making this HTTP request?

Comment: `queryParams = new {
    query = "msg_id like 'KdLh1ZETSQCWx0iqU44BTg%'", limit = 10 };                                                                                                                          
                                var client = new RestClient("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/messages");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);`

Comment: My mistake, I have taken a wrong msg_id.  Your solution works for me. Thank you for your time & solution , it helps me perfectly.